# Replacing just the Wheels on Create2

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

Is it possible to replace just the wheels on the create2 robot? Is it a standard shaft/coupling?

Answer (score 2):

The wheel is on a 5mm shaft.  It is simply pressed into the gears and housing.  However, it is very difficult to remove.  (I had to completely disassemble the wheel module to get it out.)  Also, I am not sure the wheel can be removed from the shaft.  Either the wheel is molded on the shaft or there is a metal hub on the wheel that has a very strong press fit on the shaft.

But I am not sure why you would want to replace the Roomba wheels.  They are just the right size for the robot.  I don't think the robot will work very well with wheels any larger or smaller.

However, you may be interested in this [Wheel Hack Document](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Wheel_Hack.pdf?la=en) from the Create2 site.  It describes the electrical interface between the robot and the wheel module.  This will allow you to:

1. Use your own motors, gear-train and wheels with Roomba.
2. Use the Roomba wheel modules with your own controller, without the Roomba chassis.